# SSL certificate : public key or private key?

Tags: ssl

I have read a lot about SSL certificates and I have one thing still not clear. What is the difference bewteen an SSL certificate and public key/private key?

Is a certificate (or contains) a public key? private key? both? or it has nothing to do with either of them?

I found an example of a certificate. I can see the public key, but for the certificate part, I do not know if some part of private key has already been integrated:

```
Certificate: 
    Data: 
        Version: 3 (0x2) 
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1) 
        Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption 
        Issuer: C=FJ, ST=Fiji, L=Suva, O=SOPAC, OU=ICT, CN=SOPAC Root CA/Email=administrator@sopac.org 
        Validity 
            Not Before: Nov 20 05:47:44 2001 GMT 
            Not After : Nov 20 05:47:44 2002 GMT 
        Subject: C=FJ, ST=Fiji, L=Suva, O=SOPAC, OU=ICT, CN=www.sopac.org/Email=administrator@sopac.org 
        Subject Public Key Info: 
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption  
            RSA Public Key: (1024 bit) 
                Modulus (1024 bit): 
                    00:ba:54:2c:ab:88:74:aa:6b:35:a5:a9:c1:d0:5a: 
                    9b:fb:6b:b5:71:bc:ef:d3:ab:15:cc:5b:75:73:36: 
                    b8:01:d1:59:3f:c1:88:c0:33:91:04:f1:bf:1a:b4: 
                    7a:c8:39:c2:89:1f:87:0f:91:19:81:09:46:0c:86: 
                    08:d8:75:c4:6f:5a:98:4a:f9:f8:f7:38:24:fc:bd: 
                    94:24:37:ab:f1:1c:d8:91:ee:fb:1b:9f:88:ba:25: 
                    da:f6:21:7f:04:32:35:17:3d:36:1c:fb:b7:32:9e: 
                    42:af:77:b6:25:1c:59:69:af:be:00:a1:f8:b0:1a: 
                    6c:14:e2:ae:62:e7:6b:30:e9 
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001) 
         X509v3 extensions: 
             X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                 CA:FALSE 
             Netscape Comment: 
                 OpenSSL Generated Certificate
             X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                 FE:04:46:ED:A0:15:BE:C1:4B:59:03:F8:2D:0D:ED:2A:E0:ED:F9:2F 
             X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                 keyid:E6:12:7C:3D:A1:02:E5:BA:1F:DA:9E:37:BE:E3:45:3E:9B:AE:E5:A6 
                 DirName:/C=FJ/ST=Fiji/L=Suva/O=SOPAC/OU=ICT/CN=SOPAC Root CA/Email=administrator@sopac.org 
                 serial:00
    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        34:8d:fb:65:0b:85:5b:e2:44:09:f0:55:31:3b:29:2b:f4:fd: 
        aa:5f:db:b8:11:1a:c6:ab:33:67:59:c1:04:de:34:df:08:57: 
        2e:c6:60:dc:f7:d4:e2:f1:73:97:57:23:50:02:63:fc:78:96: 
        34:b3:ca:c4:1b:c5:4c:c8:16:69:bb:9c:4a:7e:00:19:48:62: 
        e2:51:ab:3a:fa:fd:88:cd:e0:9d:ef:67:50:da:fe:4b:13:c5: 
        0c:8c:fc:ad:6e:b5:ee:40:e3:fd:34:10:9f:ad:34:bd:db:06: 
        ed:09:3d:f2:a6:81:22:63:16:dc:ae:33:0c:70:fd:0a:6c:af:
        bc:5a 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
MIIDoTCCAwqgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADCBiTELMAkGA1UEBhMCRkox 
DTALBgNVBAgTBEZpamkxDTALBgNVBAcTBFN1dmExDjAMBgNVBAoTBVNPUEFDMQww 
CgYDVQQLEwNJQ1QxFjAUBgNVBAMTDVNPUEFDIFJvb3QgQ0ExJjAkBgkqhkiG9w0B 
CQEWF2FkbWluaXN0cmF0b3JAc29wYWMub3JnMB4XDTAxMTEyMDA1NDc0NFoXDTAy 
MTEyMDA1NDc0NFowgYkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkZKMQ0wCwYDVQQIEwRGaWppMQ0wCwYD 
VQQHEwRTdXZhMQ4wDAYDVQQKEwVTT1BBQzEMMAoGA1UECxMDSUNUMRYwFAYDVQQD 
Ew13d3cuc29wYWMub3JnMSYwJAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhdhZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yQHNv 
cGFjLm9yZzCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAulQsq4h0qms1panB 
0Fqb+2u1cbzv06sVzFt1cza4AdFZP8GIwDORBPG/GrR6yDnCiR+HD5EZgQlGDIYI 
2HXEb1qYSvn49zgk/L2UJDer8RzYke77G5+IuiXa9iF/BDI1Fz02HPu3Mp5Cr3e2 
JRxZaa++AKH4sBpsFOKuYudrMOkCAwEAAaOCARUwggERMAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwLAYJ 
YIZIAYb4QgENBB8WHU9wZW5TU0wgR2VuZXJhdGVkIENlcnRpZmljYXRlMB0GA1Ud
DgQWBBT+BEbtoBW+wUtZA/gtDe0q4O35LzCBtgYDVR0jBIGuMIGrgBTmEnw9oQLl 
uh/anje+40U+m67lpqGBj6SBjDCBiTELMAkGA1UEBhMCRkoxDTALBgNVBAgTBEZp 
amkxDTALBgNVBAcTBFN1dmExDjAMBgNVBAoTBVNPUEFDMQwwCgYDVQQLEwNJQ1Qx 
FjAUBgNVBAMTDVNPUEFDIFJvb3QgQ0ExJjAkBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWF2FkbWluaXN0 
cmF0b3JAc29wYWMub3JnggEAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4GBADSN+2ULhVviRAnw 
VTE7KSv0/apf27gRGsarM2dZwQTeNN8IVy7GYNz31OLxc5dXI1ACY/x4ljSzysQb 
xUzIFmm7nEp+ABlIYuJRqzr6/YjN4J3vZ1Da/ksTxQyM/K1ute5A4/00EJ+tNL3b 
Bu0JPfKmgSJjFtyuMwxw/Qpsr7xa
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference bewteen an SSL certificate and public key/private key?

An SSL certificate wraps a public key with an authenticated identity.

> Is a certificate (or contains) a public key?

Yes.

> private key?

No.

> both?

No.

> or it has nothing to do with either of them?

See above.

> I found an example of a certificate. I can see the public key, but for the certificate part, I do not know if some part of private key has already been integrated:

It hasn't.